# NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: hangs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to instantiate an NSManagedObject, but the thread seems to hang when doing so. Here's the code:

```
    NSLog(@"here");

    WinkProfileData *profileData = [[WinkProfileData alloc] initWithEntity: entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext: delegate.managedObjectContext];

    NSLog(@"but not here");
```

`WinkProfileData` was generated using the Xcode generator. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do work asynchronously via GCD or an explicit threading mechanism? If so then have you followed the Core Data thread confinement rules? On which thread/queue was the context created? And in any case have you tried pausing execution and seeing exactly what the call stack looks like?

Comment: Please see my response! It was quite simple, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that I omitted an important part, which is where the mistake was:

```
    WinkAppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:WinkProfileDataEntityIdentifier inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];

    WinkProfileData *profileData = [[WinkProfileData alloc] initWithEntity: entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext: delegate.managedObjectContext];
```

It didn't seem relevant because it hang in the last line, but I guess it's always relevant =)

Anyway, it wouldn't be easy to find it. It so happens that the constant `WinkProfileDataEntityIdentifier` had the wrong value. It's just odd that the thread "just" hangs... Maybe there should be an error of some kind.